# How do I format Currency correctly in React using numberWithCommas Regex

Tags: reactjs, currency

I am trying to simulate data gotten from a Rest API into currency format and Decimal places etc.
When i do something like this :

```
const numberWithCommas = (x) => {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
  }
```

This code is supposed to help me to convert the data gotten from the REST api into decimal places so instead of `12345` i am supposed to have it as `1,2345.00`

When i try something, it gives me a totally white screen.

My code is looking thus

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Balance = () => {
    const[accNum, setAccNum] = useState('');
    const[accDetails, setAccDetails] = useState('');

    const numberWithCommas = (x) => {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
      }

    function getAccountBal(){
        fetch('https://financeplus.herokuapp.com/api/getaccounts/'+accNum,{
            method : 'GET',
            mode : 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        }).then((response)=>response.json()).then((responseJson)=>{
            setAccDetails(responseJson.data)
        })
    }   

    return (
        <div align="center">
            <table border="0" width="98%">
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td className="homeFormTable">
                        <table border="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <img border="0" src="images/FinancePlus_color_colorLogo.png" width="157" height="36" /></td>
                                <td width="136">
                                    <p align="center" />
                                    <li className="Logout"><Link to="/openaccount" className="ForLogout">Logout</Link></li>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <div className="upMenuTable">
                    <div className="nav-links">
                        <ul>
                            <li><Link to="/homepage">Home</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/openaccount">Account Opening</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/balance">Account Balance</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/transfers">Transfers</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/cashmgt">Deposit/Withdrawals</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="SideNav">
                    <div className="sideNav-links">
                        <ul>
                            <li><Link to="/homepage">Home</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/openaccount">Account Opening</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/balance">Account Balance</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/transfers">Transfers</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/cashmgt">Deposit/Withdrawals</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="playTable">
                    <table>
                        <div align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p align="right" />
                                    <font face="Arial Black" size="1">
                                        Account Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </font>
                                    <input type="text" name="T1" size="59" onChange ={(e) =>setAccNum(e.target.value)} className="searchBoxAcc" />
                                </td>
                                <td width="121">
                                    <p align="right" />
                                    <input onClick={getAccountBal} type="submit" value="Search" name="B1" className="searchBoxBtn" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </div>
                        <div align="center" className="infoArea">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="18%" align="right"><font face="Arial Black" size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    Full Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font>
                                </td>
                                <td width="33%" align="left">
                                    <font face="Arial Black" size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp; {accDetails.fullname}</font>
                                </td>
                                <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="21%" align="right"><font face="Arial Black" size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    Address&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font></td>
                                <td width="24%" align="left" rowspan="2">
                                    <font face="Arial Black" size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {accDetails.address}</font><p />
                                    <font face="Arial Black" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="18%" align="right"><font face="Arial Black" size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    City&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font>
                                </td>
                                <td width="33%" align="left">
                                    <font face="Arial Black" size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp; {accDetails.city}</font>
                                </td>
                                <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="18%" align="right"><font face="Arial Black" size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    Telephone&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font>
                                </td>
                                <td width="33%" align="left">
                                    <font face="Arial Black" size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp; {accDetails.tel}</font>
                                </td>
                                <td width="1%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="21%" align="right"><font face="Arial Black" size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    Balance&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font></td>
                                <td width="24%" align="left" rowspan="2">
                                    <font face="Arial Black" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {numberWithCommas(accDetails.bal.toFixed(2))} Currency = {accDetails.ccy}</font><p />
                                    <font face="Arial Black" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </div>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div className="Footer">
                    <table className="footerTable">
                        <p className="reserved"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &copy; Finance Plus 2021</p>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Balance;
```

how do I format this correctly?

Comment: what is your error in console? can you provide in your question?

Comment: Besides the issue you're having, you can also use the built-in [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) function for this.

Comment: @EkiSaputra i get this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString') but the white screen is inevitable

Comment: @Chris, but does not denote the decimal places at the back? any reason for this?

Comment: @MikeBlue what the output console if you set console.log('x is : ',x); before x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');

Comment: You can use `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits` to change that behaviour. It defaults to 0 for non-currency formats.